# Extract date from apache/niginx userid cookie

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, cookies, userid

Both webservers Apache and Nginx can give visitors uniqid cookie with mod_unique_id/userid modules. Such a [cookie looks like](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_unique_id.html) four uint32 values encoded to base64 string. Second byte is a timestamp when the cookie was issued.

I'd like to extract the date and time of it.

```
from base64 import b64decode
from datetime import datetime
import shlex, gzip, glob
from struct import unpack

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def get_data() -> pd.DataFrame:
    filenames = glob.glob('data/user_cookie/stat-*.gz')
    for filename in filenames:
        print(filename)
        f = gzip.open(filename, 'rt')
        for row in f.readlines():
            parts = shlex.split(row)
            useragent, raw_cookie = parts[9], parts[16]
            if raw_cookie == '-':
                raw_visit_date = parts[3][1:]
                # this is a first visit
                visit_date = datetime.strptime(raw_visit_date,
                                               '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S')
            else:
                visit_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(unpack('IIII',
                                                           b64decode(raw_cookie))[1])
            print(useragent, visit_date)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_data()
```

This line seems to me especially "artificial". How to make all code  more "pythonic" and faster?

```
datetime.fromtimestamp(unpack('IIII', b64decode(raw_cookie))[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean exactly by "artificial" and "pythonic", but at least on my machine, that code is incorrect. And it's incorrect in a way that will give you bogus data which might not be noticed.

The `'IIII'` format code for `unpack` does not specify a byte order, which on my (x86) machine results in an incorrect timestamp. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) says that omitting the byte order will cause it to default to your machine's byte order. But in mod_uid version 2, the cookie uses network byte order.  Specify network byte order with the format code `!IIII'`.

If by "pythonic" you mean spread it across a few lines instead of packing it into one, here is how that could look:

```
binary_cookie = b64decode(raw_cookie)
fields = unpack('!IIII', binary_cookie)
visit_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(fields[1])
```